# Mockito Spy cauing issues with Mocked Functions

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

lets say you have a function fun() in class A that I want to test fun() calls 2 dependancy fun1() and fun2() now it also calls fun3() which is of the same class A.
So here is how my class looks like :

```
class A {
    B b;
    C c;

    @Inject
    A(B b, C c) {
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    fun() {
        try {
            b.fun1();
            c.fun2("success");
        } catch (Exception) {
            c.fun2("Failure")
        }
        fun3();

    }
    fun3() {
        //Code
    }

}
```

The Test that I wrote :

```
    public class ATest {
        @Mock
        B b;
        @Mock
        C c;
        @InjectMocks
        A a;
        @Mock
        Fun1Response fun1response;

        @Test
        public void myTest() {
            when(b.fun1(any())).thenReturn(fun1response);
            A aSpy = Mockito.spy(a);
            doNothing().when(aSpy).fun3();
            doNothing().when(c).fun2(any());
            aSpy.fun();
            verify(c).fun2(eq("success"));
            verify(a).fun3();
        }
    }
```

It is giving me this error while runnign the test:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
c.fun2(<any>)
[junit] Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

Comment: You are not running the test with the Mockito extension/runner; your annotations have no effect.

Comment: Also, your code is not compiling. Your test sets up `fun1` with one argument, your production code calls it with zero arguments. Is class `B` even required to for the [mre]?

Comment: Furthermore, you are calling verify on `a` (not a mock) and not on `aSpy`. Please [edit] your question to make it actually compilable and to exhibit the problem. (and strip everything that's irrelevant from the code)

Comment: (and when I change `verify(a)` to `verify(aSpy)` and run the test with the Mockito extension, the test succeeds. Otherwise, it fails. Not with the error presented by you, but a different error)